# Is it bad practice to check if something exists before inserting

Tags: mysql, sql

Just wondering if checking if something exists before inserting is bad practice?

e.g.

1. Check username does not exist by using SELECT on database. Can tell the client that the username already exists.
2. Insert username into database (has UNIQUE). Log any error that occurs here.

or

1. Insert username into database with NOT EXISTS. If an error is returned, tell the client that the username already exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best approach is to make use of a unique constraint.  Either ignore the constraint violation (using `on duplicate key update`) or handle the error.

You can also do a check before inserting into the table.  This might let you customize the error message better (for instance, if you had multiple unique constraints on the table).  But you don't want to rely on such checks, because they are prone to race conditions.  Multiple inserts at the same time could end up inserting the same row, because each "saw" that the table did not contain that row.

Comment: it's better to check before insert because handling exception is much more expensive .it's my opinion.

Comment: @Mr.AF . . . You *still* have to handle exceptions, so that doesn't buy you very much (even if it is true, which I don't think it is on database operations).

Comment: @Mr.AF ... it may depend on use case I believe. Checking before insert does not guarantee that we will not get exception. If probability of getting duplicate exception is less, its better to handle via exception. At least it saves time of "searching for existence".

Comment: @GordonLinoff i got what you mean yeah you are right .

Comment: @bytingbee yeah when async operations comes to play it might throw exception .